# Intellij IDEA debugging on WSL

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, ip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The initial problem is debugging doesn't work when you simply click debug button, everything just kinda hangs and nothing happens. but it [says it listens on port 12345](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2L1v.png).

If you manually click "Attach debugger", which you normally don't have to do, [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWEc2.png) occurs.

After hours of figuring it out, configuring firewall, going through logs, manually starting java program, configuring remote debugger, I finally ended up in a thing called "Resource Monitor".

And when I run my java code in debug, by just clicking a button in IDEA, it showed me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCnqn.png).

So after seeing that wslhost.exe listens on port 12345 on IPv6, I googled what's the localhost of IPv6 is and tried to run my remote debugger with this [configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gODab.png).

And it worked, debugger actually connected and worked normally, now the question is, how do I make it work without manually connecting a debugger, is there a way to tell idea to listen on IPv4, or to connect debugger on IPv6?

Setup: Windows 10 19043.1266, WSL 2, IDEA installed in Windows, jdk in WSL, project is located in WSL.

Comment: What do you have in hosts file? How localhost is defined?

Comment: Windows is default with everything commented out.
This is inside wsl
[link](https://imgur.com/a/NpS9LdV)

Comment: It's a known bug in IntelliJ IDEA:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265792